# Eclipse error while running android emulator

Tags: eclipse, macos, android-emulator

So my eclipse basically freezes up on loading my android emulator whenever it sees fit.  Its not an actual error. Everything works fine but I cannot run the emulator.  I try terminating the android emulator trying to run but it wont terminate and it always stops at 27%.

I have to force quit eclipse and start it up again. It happens a lot and its really annoying to have to stop coding and restart my emulator every like 30 mins.  Ive tried restarting the computer and such and looking this up on google but still havent found anything...  Anyone know what to do or what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running Eclipse in debug mode from a terminal, with this command, from the Eclipse directory:

```
./eclipse --consolelog --debug
```